# Pandas - Read end of .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a big (8 GB) csv gzip file. I would like to read it through pandas into a DataFrame. Since the length of the file is big, I read it in chunks and it works fine but I'm interested in knowing whether is there a way to read only the last x lines, without decompressing the whole file.

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) as a file format for your data. (Yes, of course [it's supported by pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hdf5-pytables).)

Comment: I can't see how it cannot decompress the whole fie, if you know the number of rows you could see what happens if you set `skiprows=some_num` as a param to `read_csv`

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking of various ways to read the last lines of a dataframe. As I am not sure if I understood what you mean by "without decompressing the whole file" correctly, I wonder if any of the options bellow is of interest to you.

---

**Option 1**

When reading a .csv file using `pandas.read_csv()`, rows can be skipped over so they are not included in the import.

For that, when calling it one should pass `skiprows=[x]`, where x is the row number to be excluded (Note that row numbering is list-like, beginning with 0).

---

**Option 2**

Another option might be converting the file to HDF5 and select a start and stop. Here's an example

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : np.random.randn(50000)},index=pd.date_range('20200528',periods=50000,freq='s'))

store = pd.HDFStore('example.h5', mode='w')

store.append('df', df)

rowsnumber = store.get_storer('df').nrows

store.select('df',start=nrows-5,stop=rowsnumber) #Change the start to the number of rows one wants to display starting from the end
```

---

**Option 3**

Assuming that the df is already associated with the variable `df`, in order to read the last 5 rows, use [df.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

```
rows = df.iloc[-5:]
```

Or [`df.tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html)

```
rows = df.tail(5)
```